# Filter on Google Sheets keeping the first occurence of duplicate values in specific column

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, unique, textjoin

In this reading example sheet:

| ID | Date | Page | Interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1# Day | Day 1 | 1 | Day 1 - Pg. 1 |
| 2# Day | Day 2 | 2 | Day 2 - Pg. 2 |
| 3# Day | Day 3 | 3 | Day 3 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 4# Day | Day 4 | 3 | Day 4 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 5# Day | Day 5 | 3 | Day 5 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 6# Day | Day 6 | 3 | Day 6 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 7# Day | Day 7 | 3 | Day 7 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 8# Day | Day 8 | 3 | Day 8 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 9# Day | Day 9 | 3 | Day 9 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 10# Day | Day 10 | 3 | Day 10 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 11# Day | Day 11 | 3 | Day 11 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 12# Day | Day 12 | 3 | Day 12 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 13# Day | Day 13 | 3 | Day 13 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 14# Day | Day 14 | 3 | Day 14 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 15# Day | Day 15 | 3 | Day 15 - Pg. 3 of 2 |
| 16# Day | Day 16 | 2 | Day 16 - Pg. 2 |
| 17# Day | Day 17 | 2 | Day 17 - Pg. 2 |
| 18# Day | Day 18 | 2 | Day 18 - Pg. 2 |
| 19# Day | Day 19 | 2 | Day 19 - Pg. 2 |
| 20# Day | Day 20 | 2 | Day 20 - Pg. 2 |

How to use FILTER to filter Interval column, considering only the first occurence of an duplicated value in Page column to obtain a result like this:

Day 1 - Pg. 1
Day 2 - Pg. 2

I'm using FILTER(Interval,Page<=2), but the result isn't what I want. I'm getting:
Day 1 - Pg. 1
Day 2 - Pg. 2   
Day 16 - Pg. 2  
Day 17 - Pg. 2  
Day 18 - Pg. 2  
Day 19 - Pg. 2  
Day 20 - Pg. 2  
Day 21 - Pg. 2  
Day 22 - Pg. 2  
Day 23 - Pg. 2  
Day 24 - Pg. 2  
Day 25 - Pg. 2  
Day 26 - Pg. 2  
Day 27 - Pg. 2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper column.
with the formula `=COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C2)` and drag it down as you will.
and then filter your table with the formula `=FILTER(A1:D,E1:E=1,C:C<=2)`
[its should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdBEl.png)
you can copy [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yDPCMu_Inced5nZj3_BRi9BOtu70R45zYR2mlvZ_QRo/edit?usp=sharing) directly.

You can edit the criteria that you intended by changing the number in this part `C:C<=2`

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to only filter like the formula I showed? I mean - page<=2

Comment: @BrunoSilva Yes, of course it's updated now.

Comment: @BrunoSilva do you need anything else.

Comment: @BrunoSilva If the answer is satisfactory to the question, accepting the answer is greatly appreciated.